# Dynamically adding classes using JQuery .hover()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of tags and a body of text.

When the cursor hovers over the tag, I'd like the matching text in the body of text to be highlighted. I have the CSS for highlighting tested and working when the class "active" is present.

They are in different divs on the page, so sibling or parent css doesn't work.

The tags all have `<span class="taghover">tag</span>`

The body text has the appropriate words/phrases wrapped in

```
<span class="highlight (slugified phrase)">phrase</span>
```

On page load, I'd like each of the tags to have

```
.hover(addActive(text), removeActive(text))
```

where text is the slugified phrase.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function slug(Text)
{
    return Text
        .toLowerCase()
        .replace(/ /g,'-')
        .replace(/[^\w-]+/g,'')
        ;
}

function makehover() {
    var spanElements = document.querySelectorAll(".taghover");
    for (var x of spanElements) {
            var ih = slug(x.innerHTML);
            .hover(addActive(ih), removeActive(ih));
            /* x.hover(addActive(ih), removeActive(ih)); */

        }
}

function addActive(newText) {
    slugClass = concat(".",newText)
    var spanElements = document.querySelectorAll(slugClass);
    for (var x of spanElements) {
            x.classList.add("active");
        }
}

function removeActive(newText) {
    slugClass = concat(".",newText)
    var spanElements = document.querySelectorAll(slugClass);
    for (var x of spanElements) {
            x.classList.remove("active");
        }
}
```

But I'm getting the error `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.'` in makehover()

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you have `slug(x.innerHTML);` _semicolon_ and after try use _dot_

Comment: from what element or variable you try call _hover_ function?

Comment: can you provide html also? and jsfiddle?

Comment: your main problem: you have _jQuery_ in question title, but not use it in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code not use jquery, and have a few errors:

- you not declare function *hover*, *concat* and etc
- *addActive* and *removeActive* call instant instead passed as callback

So you can fix it like in code snippet below:

```js
function slug(txt) {
  return txt
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace(/ /g, '-')
    .replace(/[^\w-]+/g, '');
}

function makehover() {
  var tags = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.taghover'));
  for (var i in tags) {
    var tag = tags[i];
    var tagClass = slug(tag.innerHTML);
    addHover(tag, hoverHandler(tagClass, 'add'), hoverHandler(tagClass, 'remove'));
  }
}

function hoverHandler(spanClass, action) {
  return function() {
    this.classList[action]('active');
    var spans = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.' + spanClass));
    for (var i in spans) {
      var span = spans[i];
      span.classList[action]('active');
    }
  }
}

function addHover(span, handlerIn, handlerOut) {
  span.addEventListener('mouseenter', handlerIn.bind(span));
  span.addEventListener('mouseleave', handlerOut.bind(span));
}

makehover();
```

```css
.taghover {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #4444FF;
  background-color: #96FFFB;
  color: #0015EF;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
}
.active {
  background-color: #AAFFAA;
}
```

```html
<div>Tags:<span class="taghover">Tag 1</span><span class="taghover">Tag 2</span><span class="taghover">Tag 3</span>
</div>
Text
<div>
  <span class="tag-1">text for tag 1</span>
  <span class="tag-2">text for tag 2</span>
  <span class="tag-3">text for tag 3</span>
  <span class="tag-1">text for tag 1</span>
  <span class="tag-2">text for tag 2</span>
  <span class="tag-3">text for tag 3</span>
  <span class="tag-1">text for tag 1</span>
</div>
```

But with using jQuery it would be simple

```js
function slug(txt) {
  return txt
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace(/ /g, '-')
    .replace(/[^\w-]+/g, '');
}

$('.taghover').hover(function(){
  $('.'+slug(this.innerHTML)).addClass('active');
  }, function(){
  $('.'+slug(this.innerHTML)).removeClass('active');
})
```

```css
.taghover {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #4444FF;
  background-color: #96FFFB;
  color: #0015EF;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
}
.active {
  background-color: #AAFFAA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Tags:<span class="taghover">Tag 1</span><span class="taghover">Tag 2</span><span class="taghover">Tag 3</span>
</div>
Text
<div>
  <span class="tag-1">text for tag 1</span>
  <span class="tag-2">text for tag 2</span>
  <span class="tag-3">text for tag 3</span>
  <span class="tag-1">text for tag 1</span>
  <span class="tag-2">text for tag 2</span>
  <span class="tag-3">text for tag 3</span>
  <span class="tag-1">text for tag 1</span>
</div>
```

Comment: jQuery suggestion worked once I put an ; at the end and wrapped it in a $(document).ready(function(){
}); - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Find a working example using jQuery below. I recommend you use a `data-`attribute to store the class of the container which is supposed to be highlighted when hovering your `<span>`.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVWELZ

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hoveractivator").on('mouseover', function() {
    var attachedContainer = $(this).attr('data-container');
    $("[class^='item']").removeClass('active');
    $("."+attachedContainer).addClass('active');
  })
})
```

```css
.hoveractivator {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 60px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
.hoveractivator:hover:after {
  content: "Activator for container with class=\""attr(data-container)"\"";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -35px;
  left: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.active:after {
  content: " now active!";
}

div[class^="item"] {
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br />
<br />
<span class="hoveractivator" data-container="item1">Item 1</span>
<span class="hoveractivator" data-container="item2">Item 2</span>
<span class="hoveractivator" data-container="item3">Item 3</span>
<span class="hoveractivator" data-container="item4">Item 4</span>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div class="item1">ITEM 1 DIV</div>
<div class="item2">ITEM 2 DIV</div>
<div class="item3">ITEM 3 DIV</div>
<div class="item4">ITEM 4 DIV</div>
```